# How to select part of the text inside a H1?

Tags: html, regex, xpath, rapidminer

I am trying to find out how to select the ABCD part of the text from below h1 below using xPath on RapidMiner.

```
 <h1> 2010 ABCD EFGTTH FEEDS ASSGEAA </h1>
```

I have come with the following, but it will not return any result at all.

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring(//h1, 1, 4)/text(), ' '), ' ')
```

Could someone please give me some suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible XPath that work for this *specific* HTML input :

```
substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//h1), ' '), ' ')
```

Basically the idea is to remove leading white-spaces first, then get the substring between the first space and the next space.

**xpathtester demo link :** http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/24ce7e27ad7030f95032b5b290c57fe0

**output :** `ABCD`